# VIM "change word" equivalent in Replace mode

Tags: vim

I got used to the "change object" commands in vim: cw, ci", etc.

However, sometimes I'm working with formatted text files and want to keep the spacing. E.g., in the following example

```
abc123  efg456
```

I really wanted an `rw` command that when standing on the first `a` character and replacing the first word with just `ABC`, will replace the `123` characters with spaces. So I'll get:

```
ABC     efg456
```

(this is after typing `rwABC<esc>` when the cursor is initially on `a` and in command mode.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple mapping (not very well tested, but it works on your example). It replaces to the end of the word with spaces, and leaves you in replace mode.

```
nnoremap <leader>rw ver <esc>R
```

To use this, type `\rw`. (You could omit the `<leader>` which would allow you to type `rw` as you requested, but this will interfere with the default `r` behaviour.)

Answer (score 5):

I would do `vwr<Space>RABC<Esc>`. This applies the motion / text object (here: `w`) to make a visual selection, then blanks out the selection, then starts *Replace mode* over it.

You could create a mapping for that, but your `rw` suggestion would prevent you from using the original `r` command to replace a single character (or, if you just want this for the `w` motion, from replacing with the letter `w`).

Comment: +1 I thought of the same, but beginning with `viw`, which could do this operation even if the cursor sits in between a word.